# Writing XML Sequentially

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using XML to record a stream of data. I know, there are better data formats out there but we have our reasons!

Normally I would use an XmlDocument to store xml data in memory and then write the whole thing out. That's not really much help here because how long we record the data stream for is not specified and probably unlikely to be fixed at any period short enough not to run out of memory.

What would the best approach be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use an [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx). The tricky bit will be knowing when to close the document - before you do so, it won't be valid XML; after you've done so, you can't append to it any more.

Note that you don't have to use `XmlWriter` *directly*. For example, using LINQ to XML (my preferred XML API; *much* nicer than the `XmlDocument` etc classes) you could create the writer, write out any "header" information (e.g. the opening tags for the container), then create `XElement` objects for each value you want to write, and call `element.WriteTo(writer)`.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml"))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("log");
            writer.WriteStartElement("entries");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                XElement element = new XElement("entry", "Entry " + i);
                element.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll have a look at the Linq stuff - I hadn't realised there was another XML Api out there!

Comment: @Nick: It was introduced in .NET 3.5. If you're still on .NET 2.0 or 3.0 you'll need to use another approach - but probably still involving XmlWriter.

Answer (score 1):

> [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only means of generating streams or files containing XML data.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best approach is using the XmlWriter class, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz7cs0d.aspx).